# Can pvc fittings and pvc pipe be used to install tube and shower fixture

Tags: shower, bathtub, bathroom-fixtures

Can pvc fittings and pipe be used to install tub and shower fixture.

Answer (score 1):

I might be confusing PVC with CPVC.  They're both plastic pipes that are glued together, but they are different products.

PVC can be used only for drain lines (including indoors, despite what the answer below says). If you want to use it for your tub and shower drain, you can.

CPVC can be used for water supply lines, and you can use it for the connection between the shower valve and the shower spout.  However, you should not use CPVC for the connection between the valve and the tub spout.  The reason is that CPVC has a narrow diameter and might restrict flow out of the tub spout, causing some water to leak out of the shower instead.

You'll also want to make sure your valve accepts CPVC connections.  If it has brass or Pex connections, you'll need to use an adapter; you can only glue CPVC to CPVC.

Answer (score -1):

PVC is not used for indoor plumbing.  It cannot take the heat of heated water.  CPVC is approved and will work as well as all of the PEX products. If you use the CPVC glue dry time is 4 to 6 hours.

Comment: You're correct when it comes to not having PVC allowed within 18" of the outflow of a water heater, and other piping (ie. copper) is used there. However, PVC is allowed throughout the remainder of plumbing for houses commonly in the US.